# Play a video on the default media player from a Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, xaml, video, windows-store-apps

I want to implement a function that plays a video in the default media player from a windows store apps that uses Xaml and C#.

I don't want to embed the player I want to open a new window with the default player and tell it to play the selected file.

All the samples that I've found are to create an embedded player or send to a device.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks...

Comment: In windows if you call Process.Start(somefile.ext) it opens the file with the default app associated. Or call Process.Start(@"some\path\to\mediaplayer.exe", "somefile.wmv"). I am commenting this instead of answering as I don't know if it sit he same for Windows mobile.

Comment: Sorry that was one of my first tries. That method is not available for windows store app development.